# Strangest thing ever (Java and Angular (simple))

Tags: java, angular, maven

I have an angular and a spring boot project together.

I can't load anything from the assets of Spring Boot using (I tried like 50 different paths nothing works) I copy the path from intellij

```
 this.image = (image == null) ? Files.readAllBytes(new File("static/images/default-user-image.jpg").toPath()) : image;
```

But I can from the frontend app

```
 this.image = (image == null) ? Files.readAllBytes(new File("src/frontend/src/assets/images/add.png").toPath()) : image;
```

I think it's because of maven but I don't know what

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>ng</executable>
                <workingDirectory>src/frontend</workingDirectory>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>build</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: maybe it's that workingDir. But I need it to build the frontend to the static

Comment: the two file path examples are completely different from one another... why is that?

Comment: Are you sure 'static/images/' is correct? It seems this 'static/images/' is not within the same context of the angular app.

Comment: If you are using maven to build your angular + spring-boot application, Then I would suggest you to try https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin